# Constructor Argument Unrecognized

Tags: c++, constructor

I am getting a compiler error when trying to construct an instance of nested class `A::B` in the following code:

```
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

struct A{
    int n;

    A():
    n(1){}

    struct B{
        A& a;

        B(A a):
        a(a){
            a.n=2;
        }

        ~B(){
            a.n=0;
        }
    };
};

int main() {
    A a;
    printf("%d\n",a.n);
    do{
        A::B(a);
        printf("%d\n",a.n);
    }while(false);
    printf("%d\n",a.n);
    return 0;
}
```

When I call the constructor of `A::B` the compiler does not recognize the argument. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This requires at the very least posting the actual code you are using to construct the `Locker` and the actual compile error you are getting.

Comment: @Barry Now with a better example.

Comment: @xiver77 `A::B(a);`  This does not do what you think it does.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Could you explain me a bit more?

Comment: @xiver77 MUCH better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line doesn't do what you think it does:

```
A::B(a);
```

The parentheses are actually superfluous. That line is equivalent to:

```
A::B a;
```

And there's no default constructor for `B`, hence the compile error. You need to provide a name for the object, which you can call `_` as additional indication that it's just there as a scope guard:

```
A::B _(a);
```

Comment: Also his constructor is making a copy and has a dangling reference in there too.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a variant of the most vexing parse. The code:

```
CriticalSection::Locker(cs);
```

...doesn't define an object of type `CriticalSection::Locker` because you haven't supplied an argument to the ctor as needed.

The cure is to define the name of the object:

```
CriticalSection::Locker lock(cs);
```

You could also use "universal" initialization:

```
CriticalSection::Locker lock{cs};
```

This way, if you accidentally leave out the name of the object you're trying to define, you'll probably get an error message that's at least a little clearer about what's going on.

As an aside: unless you're pretty sure you gain something from using the wx variants, I'd at least consider using `std::mutex` and `std::lock_guard` instead.